# Regex quantifiers not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

I can't seem to figure out regular expression quantifiers. Something as simple as look for "..." does not work for me.

This is my pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.{3}");
```

Am I understanding something wrong? The expression "X{n}" means, take X exactly n times?

But Strings like "...." work just fine, even though it isn't exactly 3 times.

Comment: This regex should work fine. Maybe you are not using it correctly. Post code example with description of what you are trying to achieve and what you get instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that since `...` returns also true for `....` then you are using `find` method from Matcher class. Now I can see at least two things you want to achieve:

1. you want to check if entire string is only `...`
2. you want to check if string contains `...` but only if it is exactly 3 dots, so you don't want to accept `...` if it has some additional dot before or after it.

To solve case one you simply need to use `matches` method like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.{3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("...");
System.out.println(m.matches());//returns true
m = p.matcher("....");
System.out.println(m.matches());//returns false
```

To solve second case you will need to use [negative-look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism to explicitly say that there shouldn't be any dots before or after `...` so your regex can look like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\.)\\.{3}(?!\\.)");
```

and now you can just use `find` method like you probably earlier did.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("some... words. with dots.. after..... them...");
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group()+" found at position "+m.start());
```

which will print

```
... found at position 4
... found at position 42
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends the method you use, if you use the `find` method or `lookingAt`, since there is `\\.{3}` inside `....` you will obtain a match, because the three dots are found.

To match exactly a pattern from the begining to the end of the string, you need the method `matches`

Or you can use anchors for start `^` and end `$` of the string:

```
with lookingAt: \\.{3}$
with find:      ^\\.{3}$
```

Anchors are not needed with `matches`.

If you need to find exactly `...` inside a larger string with the `find` method, you need to use a lookbehind and a lookahead assertion to ensure there is no dot after and before:

```
(?<!\\.)\\.{3}(?!\\.)    # not preceded by a dot, not followed by a dot
```